# Searching data from mysql tables with relationship

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables Rentals and Units. Each Rental have one or more units. Rental has city, region, suburb and type. Unit has size and price. 
I want to get list of rentals with following filters on them:

Get All rentals where city=C AND region=R AND suburb=S AND type=T

Above is fairly easy to do but the problem is what if in the same query I want to get those rentals whose units are between 50 to 100 square meters? and also the rentals should be sorted with highest unit price. For example if some one wants to see in C city what rentals are available in specific size range X-Y, in order of cheapest rentals on top (that would come from unit price).

I can successfully get the result but I don't know how to group rentals.

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT** RENTALS.*,cities.name as cname, suburbs.name as sname, regions.name as rname
FROM RENTALS,cities,suburbs,regions,UNITS 
WHERE UNITS.rid=RENTALS.id AND RENTALS.city=cities.id AND RENTALS.suburb=suburbs.id
    AND RENTALS.region=regions.id AND RENTALS.city='4' AND RENTALS.region='4'
    AND RENTALS.suburb IN (228,232,213) AND RENTALS.sector IN ('Warehouse') 
    AND UNITS.size IN ('16 - 50 m2','51 - 100 m2')
ORDER BY if(UNITS.total_rate_parsed = '999999999' or UNITS.total_rate_parsed is null,1,0),UNITS.total_rate_parsed DESC
```

Comment: It's not clear the format of data in table UNITS. Is it "num - num m2"?

Comment: What do you mean by **GROUP** the rentals? You should share the result set of the above query and what you want it to be. (Possibly, a simplified version of the query, its result set and your goal)